# jquery fadeOut div unable to fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have adapted this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/onqn2gjj/4/ to fade my search bar out on scroll, but once the search bar is gone, I cannot get it back by clicking the search icon.

How can I modify my script to stop this from happening please?

Here is the website: http://uwinat.o2clite.com/

Thanks

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(window).scroll(function() {

if ($(this).scrollTop()>0)
 {
    $('.search').fadeOut();
 }
else
 {
  $('.search').fadeIn();
 }
   })
});
```

Comment: post your code with search bar dom element

Comment: I'd say the scroll event firing multiple times is doing something weird with the animation queue. You'd probably want to queue the animation once and stop any pending animation before it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is because on scroll you are hiding the parent of your element

**you can see it here:** http://screencast.com/t/zrnNrbeI

**If you fix that it will work:**http://screencast.com/t/H2m7K1636VER

**Note**

*I also recomend you to use a debouncer for you scrolling event... the scroll event by it self would kill your performance...  the UnderscoreJS library has a good one.*

*Also try using css animations instead of Jquery. You should always avoid using javascript animations...*

Comment: That's just the jQuery `fadeOut` animation. It animates the opacity and at the end it just sets `display` to `none`.

Comment: Hey MinusFour, could I get it to display again once the search icon is clicked again? Or is there a better script for the whole thing? Basically remove the search bar on scroll down and on click make it appear again? Thanks so much

Comment: I Nicole, check the screenshots above, that's showing you what is wrong... you cannot see the search bar because you are hiding the parent container when you scroll

Comment: @Nicole, well, we can't tell what your search icon button is doing, you'd need to put the code.

Comment: Thanks, I think it's time to go to the theme devs for this one guys. I don't know where the search jquery is to be honest. I guess Leo's answer is correct as I have changed the display rule in the inspector, which worked, but I don't know where the jquery for the search icon element is.

Comment: The event is called from the controller.js
the file is located at `/wp-content/themes/unitheme/js/controller.js`

Comment: `$('.header .search-toggle').on('click', function(){
 $('.header .search').addClass('animated');
 $('.header-cont').addClass('search-active');
});`

Comment: Also make sure your dev team, concatenate and minify your dependencies, you have too many unnecessary HTTP request...

Comment: Leo, it is a theme purchased from themeforest, also I am not sure what part of the code is applying the display:none rule to the search bar. - jQuery newbie sadly, but I'm sure you've picked that up by now :)

Comment: I see... just go to the `controller.js` file you will find the event handler there. It's a click event assigned to `$('.header .search-toggle')` If you have any other question feel free to let me know :)

Comment: Hi Leo, sorry to be a pain, I have found the click event here:

            $('.header .search-toggle').on('click', function(){
    $('.header .search').addClass('animated');
    $('.header-cont').addClass('search-active');
   });

   $('.header .search span').on('click', function(){
    $('.header .search').removeClass('animated');
    $('.header-cont').removeClass('search-active');
   }); 

What do I need to modify here please? Is it the removeClass('search-active');

Comment: Hi Nicole, sorry for replying so late. There is a file in your project. `searchbar.js` this file is hiding your element after scrolling... is using the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods from jQuery. the way these function works is they animate the opacity of your element and when it finish it set the CSS property `display` (inline) to block or none.  The `.search` element is the parent that cointains your textbox... as long as you keep the parent hidden its childrens will never be visible. you need to remove this onScroll event from the `searhbar.js` file.